# Drag & Drop to VLC using QDrag on Mac OS X

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, vlc

I've made a drag & drop implementation using QDrag. Here's the related code:

```
// ...

// Init URL List
QList<QUrl> uriList;

// Add Files To URI List
uriList << QUrl("file:///Users/Max/file1.avi");
uriList << QUrl("file:///Users/Max/file2.avi");

// Create Drag
QDrag* drag = new QDrag(this);
// Create Mime Data
QMimeData* mimeData = new QMimeData;

// Set URLS
mimeData->setUrls(uriList);

// Set Mime Data
drag->setMimeData(mimeData);

// ...

// Exec Drag
Qt::DropAction dropAction = drag->exec(Qt::CopyAction | Qt::MoveAction | Qt::LinkAction);

// Check Drop Action
if (dropAction == Qt::IgnoreAction) {
    // ...
}

// ...
```

The code runs OK in finder, Skype, Qt creator, etc...
Only VLC doesn't seem to accept the drop.

Does anybody know if there is some extra special magic needs to be done for VLC?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does VLC accept native drops at all?

Comment: Yes, it does work with native drops. When I drag over a file to drop onto vlc, it is showing a yelllow-ish border around the playlist indicating the activity. With my drops it doesn't even show that. However Finder does show similar with my drops as well. I checked the data from Finder, to drop it into my app, it does seem to use uri list as well as I do.

Comment: Update: it seems VLC does accept the drops made by my implementation if there are already other items in the playlist. It doesn't accept if the playlist is empty.